# Why can't I map @timestamp to _timestamp in Elastic Search indexing Template?

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, logstash

I am using Logstash with Elasticsearch and as a result, the @timestamp field is a mandatory document field.  The value of the `@timestamp` field is always of the ISO8601 format.

Some of the *events*/*documents* coming from Logstash don't have a special `timestamp` field (**please don't mistaken this with the _timestamp field; this is another field obtained from the grok parsing**) so I have decided to map `@timestamp` to `_timestamp` using the following indexing template:

```
{
  "settings" : {...},
  "template" : "logstash-myindex-*",
  "mappings": {
    "_id" : {
      "path": "myid"
    },
    "_timestamp" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "stored" : true,
      "path" : "@timestamp",
      "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    },
    "property" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
      },
      "myid" : {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I performed a search:

```
POST logstash-myindex-2014.12.16/_search
{
  "fields": ["_timestamp", "_source"],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I get back results as such (just showing one sample document):

```
{
    "_id": "AUeo39n78xpe_2ggb", 
    "_index": "logstash-myindex-2014.12.16", 
    "_score": 1.0, 
    "_source": {
      "@timestamp": "2014-12-16T13:47:09.703Z", 
      "@version": "1", 
      "myid": "AUeo39n78xpe_2ggb"
      "timestamp": 1418737629,
    }, 
    "_type": "logs",
    "fields": {
      "_timestamp": 1418737629000
    }
}
```

Ok, so here you can see the `path` attribute of `_id` working.  It takes the value of the field `myid` and applies it to `_id`.

Now, onwards to `_timestamp`.  This is where it gets weird.  Not only does it not take the value of `@timestamp` (2014-12-16T13:47:09.703Z), it instead takes the value of the *special timestamp field* (as mentioned this is a field obtained from grok parsing the original log message) and then converts it to milliseconds.

The desired outcome would be that `_timestamp` will assume whatever value `@timestamp` holds.  Can someone please tell me what's going on here?  Anyone experienced this before?  Is there some kind of clash between a field called `timestamp` and Elastic Search's `_timestamp` field?

Answer (score 0):

Internally in Elasticsearch all dates are stored as Epoch milliseconds - so the `_timestamp` format looks good.

Using the [Epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) a timestamp of `1418737629000` converts to `Tue, 16 Dec 2014 13:47:09 GMT`.

This looks pretty close to your `@timestamp` value - the milliseconds have been dropped, that's all. Possibly there's a time zone change that's thrown you?

Comment: Ok....but I have seen the _timestamp value being set to a date string before when I use the path attribute.  Are you saying that _timestamp value will always be in Epoch milliseconds and not assume any other format?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#date) _"Internally, a date maps to a number type long, with the added parsing stage from string to long and from long to string"_

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you lay it out for me?  I read the documentation many times....but I don't understand it.  Can you not quote from the documentation please?  Are you saying that the `_timestamp` value will never be of the form _2014-12-16T13:47:09.703Z_ even though I set the path of `_timestamp` to be `@timestamp`?

Comment: I'm saying that all dates with Elasticsearch are stored as a number. When you bring back the stored date field (any date field) then Elasticsearch will give you a number. To convert it back from the number / epoch format to a date string, either use a script or get your application UI to do the conversion.

Comment: Ok, so when you say "_when you bring back the stored date field_", do you mean when I set `store=true` on a date field?  Sorry, I'm really just that slow at picking this up.

Comment: I'm referring to when you return the field in a query. When your query returns a stored date field it will give you a number.

Comment: "_returns a stored date field_" Does this mean a date field with `store=true`?  Yes or no?

Comment: In order to return an individually stored field you need to have stored it. So yes - to store it, set store=true.